# Why onSubscribe does not work in rxjava?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, behaviorsubject, publishsubject

when I run below code if I don't write `observeOn` line, app crashes because `getView().showBlockLayout(isBlock);` invoke a method that try to hide or show a layout.
but I tried to change below `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` to `subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` and app crashes again!

```
subscription.add(UserStore.getInstance().getBlockObservable(databaseHelper.getConference().getUserChatId())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Boolean isBlock) {
                    getView().showBlockLayout(isBlock);
                    databaseHelper.getConference().setBlock(isBlock);
                    mConferenceModel.setBlock(isBlock);
                }
            }));
```

I also test this:

```
subscription.add(UserStore.getInstance().getBlockObservable(databaseHelper.getConference().getUserChatId())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Boolean isBlock) {
                    getView().showBlockLayout(isBlock);
                    databaseHelper.getConference().setBlock(isBlock);
                    mConferenceModel.setBlock(isBlock);
                }
            }));
```

and unexpectedly it worked and did not crash! I didn't use subscribeOn in getBlockObservable method(because I know we can set it once)

it's my `UserStore` class

```
PublishSubject<Pair<String,Boolean>> mObservableBlock;

private UserStore(){
    mObservableBlock = PublishSubject.create();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static UserStore getInstance() {
    if(mInstance == null)
        new UserStore();
    return mInstance;
}

public Observable<Boolean> getBlockObservable(final String userId){
    return mObservableBlock
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .filter(new Func1<Pair<String,Boolean>, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(Pair<String,Boolean> s) {
            if(userId.equals(s.first))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }).map(new Func1< Pair<String, Boolean>, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean call(Pair<String, Boolean> UserBlock) {
            return UserBlock.second;
        }
    });
}
public void publishBlockedUser(String userId,boolean isBlock){
    mObservableBlock.onNext(new Pair<String, Boolean>(userId,isBlock));
}
```

and here is how I imported rxjava dependency in gradle

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
```

Comment: When you change the`.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` to `subscribeOn` (and it still crashes) what is the argument you're passing to the `subscribeOn` call?

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) if I don't have observeOn it crashes

Comment: it crash because i try to change something in UI thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this [medium artice](https://medium.com/upday-devs/rxjava-subscribeon-vs-observeon-9af518ded53a):

> One important fact is that subscribeOn does not work with Subjects.

So you can't use subscribeOn with subjects and we have to use `observerOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` before subscription.
so all downstream methods are called on mainThread after that.

check this [medium artice](https://medium.com/upday-devs/rxjava-subscribeon-vs-observeon-9af518ded53a)